# Php artisan horizon error when build container

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, aws-fargate, laravel-horizon

i have an application written in laravel and i should manage queues through laravel HORIZON this application i should put it in a container and then deploy on AWS Fargate.
But strange things happen to me like for example:

1.This is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
 git \
 curl \
 libpng-dev \
 libonig-dev \
 libxml2-dev \
 zip \
 unzip \
 supervisor

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
 &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
 &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

WORKDIR /app
COPY horizon.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/horizon.conf
COPY composer.json .
RUN composer install --no-scripts
COPY .  .
RUN php artisan horizon
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

If in the Dockerfile there is `RUN php artisan horizon` command then during the build of the image I get this error
[image: error]

2.if instead of `php artisan horizon` I put `php artisan horizon:start` then the build of the image is successful and the container starts but horizon is not active
[image: horizon dashboard]

3.I tried to put `php artisan horizon` command under the CMD command of the Dockerfile `CMD bash -c "php artisan horizon && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80"` it goes in a loop the service I see the logs from AWS cloudwatch [image: aws cloudwatch]

The container goes into an active state but keeps restarting... anyone have any idea?

Comment: So, you must run `php artisan horizon`, that starts horizon supervisor on that instance. If you want this instance to only run horizon (you should never mix workers (horizon) with API/UI), you must use `CMD php artisan horizon`, but it is also true that if horizon crashes, the whole container goes down because it is `CMD`, so using supervisor would not work... So, I think you need to trigger `CMD` with `Supervisor`, not sure as I have not used it extensively, so if supervisor goes down, the container goes down

Comment: @matiaslauriti basically you tell me to use Supervisor instead of Horizon ... with for example the following commands 
`COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
  CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]`
but what is the difference between Supervisor Horizon? Reading in the various forums I realized that Horizon is much more independent and complete as it uses Redis

Comment: So, when you literally run `php artisan horizon` that tells horizon to start working, so all workers get created based on configuration and all of that, but if `php artisan horizon` crashes or stops, the whole container goes down, because remember your image is using `CMD php artisan horizon`, so when that process ends, the container using that image also stops. If you run `CMD` with the supervisor process (I am not sure where it is or how you start it), supervisor will internally run `php artisan horizon`, so if it crashes, it goes up again, so `supervisor` must stop to get the container down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved with laravel octane by taking the code from this GitHub account https://github.com/exaco/laravel-octane-dockerfile/blob/main/Dockerfile ...
I hope I have been useful to you

```
# Accepted values: 8.1 - 8.0
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.1

ARG COMPOSER_VERSION=latest

###########################################
# PHP dependencies
###########################################

FROM composer:${COMPOSER_VERSION} AS vendor
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY composer* ./
RUN composer install \
  --no-dev \
  --no-interaction \
  --prefer-dist \
  --ignore-platform-reqs \
  --optimize-autoloader \
  --apcu-autoloader \
  --ansi \
  --no-scripts \
  --audit

###########################################

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-cli-buster

LABEL maintainer="Seyed Morteza Ebadi <seyed.me720@gmail.com>"

ARG WWWUSER=1000
ARG WWWGROUP=1000
ARG TZ=UTC

# Accepted values: app - horizon - scheduler
ARG CONTAINER_MODE=app

ARG APP_WITH_HORIZON=false
ARG APP_WITH_SCHEDULER=false

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    TERM=xterm-color \
    CONTAINER_MODE=${CONTAINER_MODE} \
    APP_WITH_HORIZON=${APP_WITH_HORIZON} \
    APP_WITH_SCHEDULER=${APP_WITH_SCHEDULER}

ENV ROOT=/var/www/html
WORKDIR $ROOT

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-eou", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get upgrade -yqq; \
    pecl -q channel-update pecl.php.net; \
    apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress \
          apt-utils \
          gnupg \
          gosu \
          git \
          curl \
          wget \
          libcurl4-openssl-dev \
          ca-certificates \
          supervisor \
          libmemcached-dev \
          libz-dev \
          libbrotli-dev \
          libpq-dev \
          libjpeg-dev \
          libpng-dev \
          libfreetype6-dev \
          libssl-dev \
          libwebp-dev \
          libmcrypt-dev \
          libonig-dev \
          libzip-dev zip unzip \
          libargon2-1 \
          libidn2-0 \
          libpcre2-8-0 \
          libpcre3 \
          libxml2 \
          libzstd1 \
          procps

###########################################
# pdo_mysql
###########################################

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql;

###########################################
# zip
###########################################

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip && docker-php-ext-install zip;

###########################################
# mbstring
###########################################

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring;

###########################################
# GD
###########################################

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
            --prefix=/usr \
            --with-jpeg \
            --with-webp \
            --with-freetype \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd;

###########################################
# OPcache
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_OPCACHE=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_OPCACHE} = true ]; then \
      docker-php-ext-install opcache; \
  fi

###########################################
# PHP Redis
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PHPREDIS} = true ]; then \
      pecl -q install -o -f redis \
      && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
      && docker-php-ext-enable redis; \
  fi

###########################################
# PCNTL
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_PCNTL=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PCNTL} = true ]; then \
      docker-php-ext-install pcntl; \
  fi

###########################################
# BCMath
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_BCMATH=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_BCMATH} = true ]; then \
      docker-php-ext-install bcmath; \
  fi

###########################################
# RDKAFKA
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_RDKAFKA=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_RDKAFKA} = true ]; then \
      apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress librdkafka-dev \
      && pecl -q install -o -f rdkafka \
      && docker-php-ext-enable rdkafka; \
  fi

###########################################
# OpenSwoole/Swoole extension
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_SWOOLE=true
ARG SERVER=openswoole

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SWOOLE} = true ]; then \
      apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress libc-ares-dev \
      && pecl -q install -o -f -D 'enable-openssl="yes" enable-http2="yes" enable-swoole-curl="yes" enable-mysqlnd="yes" enable-cares="yes"' ${SERVER} \
      && docker-php-ext-enable ${SERVER}; \
    fi

###########################################################################
# Human Language and Character Encoding Support
###########################################################################

ARG INSTALL_INTL=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_INTL} = true ]; then \
      apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ \
      && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
      && docker-php-ext-install intl; \
  fi

###########################################
# Memcached
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_MEMCACHED=false

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MEMCACHED} = true ]; then \
      pecl -q install -o -f memcached && docker-php-ext-enable memcached; \
  fi

###########################################
# MySQL Client
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=true

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT} = true ]; then \
      apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress default-mysql-client; \
  fi

###########################################
# pdo_pgsql
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_PDO_PGSQL=false

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PDO_PGSQL} = true ]; then \
      docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql; \
  fi

###########################################
# pgsql
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_PGSQL=false

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PGSQL} = true ]; then \
      docker-php-ext-install pgsql; \
  fi

###########################################
# pgsql client and postgis
###########################################

ARG INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=false
ARG INSTALL_POSTGIS=false

RUN if [ ${INSTALL_PG_CLIENT} = true ]; then \
      . /etc/os-release \
      && echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $VERSION_CODENAME-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
      && curl -sL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
      && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress postgresql-client-12 postgis; \
      if [ ${INSTALL_POSTGIS} = true ]; then \
        apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends --show-progress postgis; \
      fi; \
  fi

###########################################
# Laravel scheduler
###########################################

RUN if [ ${CONTAINER_MODE} = 'scheduler' ] || [ ${APP_WITH_SCHEDULER} = true ]; then \
      wget -q "https://github.com/aptible/supercronic/releases/download/v0.2.1/supercronic-linux-amd64" \
           -O /usr/bin/supercronic \
      && chmod +x /usr/bin/supercronic \
      && mkdir -p /etc/supercronic \
      && echo "*/1 * * * * php ${ROOT}/artisan schedule:run --verbose --no-interaction" > /etc/supercronic/laravel; \
  fi

###########################################

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP octane \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-log-init --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u $WWWUSER octane

RUN apt-get clean \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && rm /var/log/lastlog /var/log/faillog

COPY . .
COPY --from=vendor ${ROOT}/vendor vendor

RUN mkdir -p \
  storage/framework/{sessions,views,cache} \
  storage/logs \
  bootstrap/cache \
  && chown -R octane:octane \
  storage \
  bootstrap/cache \
  && chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

COPY deployment/octane/supervisord* /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
COPY deployment/octane/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/octane.ini
COPY deployment/octane/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

RUN chmod +x deployment/octane/entrypoint.sh
RUN cat deployment/octane/utilities.sh >> ~/.bashrc

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["deployment/octane/entrypoint.sh"]

HEALTHCHECK --start-period=5s --interval=2s --timeout=5s --retries=8 CMD php artisan octane:status || exit 1
```